# Incorrect modulo result with double

Tags: java

My code is as follows (Java):

```java
long num = 988530483551494950L;
int r1 = (int) (num % (Math.pow(10, 9) + 7));
int r2 = (int) (num % 1000000007);
System.out.println(r1); // 631781580
System.out.println(r2); // 631781618
```

`r1` and `r2` should be the same, but they are not, why? Is it because `Math.pow(10, 9) + 7` is a `double`? If so, why does the `double` type cause the problem? The `double` isn't a fraction, shouldn't the result be consistent?

Comment: Fundamentally, you're using two different operators: one is an integer-based operator, the other is a double-based operator. I'm not surprised that the results are different - just as 16 / 3.0 isn't the same as 16 / 3.

Comment: Note that you don't need the `Math.pow` call here - `(int) (988530483551494950L % 1000000007d)` and `(int) (988530483551494950L % 1000000007)` give the same results as shown (which differ from each other in the same way, of course).

Comment: `num` is promoted to double and `System.out.printf("%f%n", (double)num);` prints `988530483551494910.0` so the issue seems to be in that conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numeric promotion is applied when you use `%` with a `long` and a `double` operand. The `long` is converted to a `double`, and then the remainder operation is carried out.

However, `double` cannot represent the value 988530483551494950 precisely. The closest representation represents the value 988530483551494912 (See the [conversion here](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=057056056053051048052056051053053049052057052057053048)).

And indeed, the remainder of 988530483551494912 divided by 10000000007 is 631781580 - the "wrong" answer you got.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator works differently with integers and decimals. In In your code, `r2` is the result of the operator for integers, and `r1` is for decimals (Result of `Math#pow` is `double`). If you want `r1 == r2`, then:

- Make num a double type.
- Cast Math.pow(10, 9) + 7 to int or long
- Make `1000000007` a double type (`1000000007d`)

*(Use **one** of these solutions)*

I hope I helped you.